# Configuring gunicorn without virtualenv

Tags: django, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm setting up a django site without virtualenv and I'm following [digital ocean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file) to setup which has been going fine till I had to setup gunicorn service instance which has a field `ExecStart` which I've had to remove also while trying to test.

When I try to start gunicorn I get the following error

```
root@samuel-pc:~/revamp# systemctl start gunicorn
Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.service' for details.
root@samuel-pc:~/revamp#
```

My gunicorn service code is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/revamp
#ExecStart=gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/rev$


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the way I've setup the site is I login via root and I copied the folder directly into root. The django application is called revamp and if you run pwd from inside the folder you get the result `/root/revamp`

**UPDATE**

I've edited the execstart to

```
ExecStart=gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application
```

and now when I run `systemctl status gunicorn.service`
 I get

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 28 21:48:16 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 28 21:48:16 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 28 21:53:29 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 05:05:06 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 05:05:06 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 05:05:24 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 05:05:24 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Answer (score 4):

you can find the path of your gunicorn installation by typing

```
which gunicorn
```

for me (with a regular install) this returned

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
```

so in the end you will have something like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that Gunicorn is not going to start without the `ExecStart` instruction, there's nothing to run, so the service simply returns.

It doesn't matter if your Gunicorn is installed inside a Virtualenv or not, the first argument to your Gunicorn call should be the route to your `wsgi.py` module's `application` variable.

Lets say the `wsgy.py` file is inside `/root/revamp/my_project/`

Your Gunicorn call should be:

```
gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application ...
```

Where `my_project` is the name of the module (the folder with the `__init__.py` file inside) that contains the `wsgi.py` file, and should also contain the `settings.py` file.

If you don't point it to a valid WSGI python application, Gunicorn is not going to start...